# How to create a user for newly cloned High Volume Customer Portal profile?

Tags: customer-portal

I created a profile called **Test Portal profile** by cloning High Volume Customer Portal profile. I wanna add users to Test Portal profile. i am unable to add users to this profile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't add High Volume Customer portal users from setup screen. You have go to Contact and click Manage External Users button and create new user with appropriate user profile.

Please make sure related Contact's Account owner has User Role before doing this.

Thanks,
Leanas Nixon.

Comment: You can certainly do that from set up screen

Comment: You can edit the High Volume Customer Portal Users from the User Setup screen but you do need to add them from the contact record, so in this scenario of updating existing records it is correct to do it from the User Setup screen.

Comment: You can modify the already created High Volume Customer Portal User. You can create only from Contact's Manage External user button only. Screenshot you have posted is for updating an user (Refer User Edit: Andy Young). If it is for create user, it will be "New User, User Edit."

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go to Set up | Manage Users | User

Once you are on user record then you can edit the user record and change profile to newly added one.

Alternately if you want this in bulk ,export  users (only those which you need to change profile .query with profile name High Volume portal user )via data loader and update the profileId with Id of the new profile

[image]

Comment: Hi Shrivasthava,
I already tried as you said. But new profile Test portal profile is not coming under profile list.

Comment: Try changing the User license on User record .The profile depends on User license .

Comment: Added screen shot as well of that helps